# Is it possible to reuse the views in ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, memory-management, imageview, viewflipper, reusability

May be a dumb Question.But still, is it possible to reuse the views in viewflipper?
Now,i have three imageviews in a viewflipper.is it possible to have a single imageview and change the source to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably reuse view if you want to take care of the bookkeeping your self. However the viewflipper requires at least 2 views.  From the [Android ViewFlipper Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html):

> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between **two or more views**
>   that have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.

Comment: The `ViewFlipper` doesn't insist to contain at least two views. It just doesn't make sense to have a `ViewFlipper` with on child only or even zero (like for any layout view).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the `ImageView` from the `ViewFlipper` and then put it somewhere else. You can't put it into two `ViewGroup`s at the same time (you'll get an exception that the view has already a parent).

But this is an overhead which you simply don't need to do. Simply create new `ImageView`s and use them. The memory consuming part of an `ImageView` is not the object itself but the bitmap it draws so I really recommend to read [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/drawable-mutations.html).